# Make absolute positioned div fit content width and overflow parent with horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css

I have a bootstrap modal with product info. On that modal is a an additional images section that needs to be horizontal scroll-able. I have gotten it to work but I have to sent a fixed width. Is there anyway I can make this absolute div fit the content width without dropping images to a new line?

```
<div class="additional-images-container">
  <div>
    <img width="100px" height="100px" src="">
    <img width="100px" height="100px" src="">
    <img width="100px" height="100px" src="">
    <img width="100px" height="100px" src="">
    <img width="100px" height="100px" src="">
    <img width="100px" height="100px" src="">
    <img width="100px" height="100px" src="">
    <img width="100px" height="100px" src="">
  </div>
</div>

.additional-images-container {
    height: 120px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    position: relative;
}

.additional-images-container div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200%;
}
```

Again, what I need is the child div to auto size its width and overflow the parent with a horizontal scroll bar(when needed). I cannot used jQuery to do this btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Literally figured it out right after posting this question and spending hours lol.

Just removed the width: 200%; and replaced with min-width: max-content;

Answer (score 0):

use `white-space: nowrap;` in parent div. and `display: inline-block;` child div for images.

```css
.additional-images-container {
    height: 120px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    position: relative;    
    white-space: nowrap;
}


.additional-images-container div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="additional-images-container">
  <div>
    <img width="100px" height="100px" src="">
    <img width="100px" height="100px" src="">
    <img width="100px" height="100px" src="">
    <img width="100px" height="100px" src="">
    <img width="100px" height="100px" src="">
    <img width="100px" height="100px" src="">
    <img width="100px" height="100px" src="">
    <img width="100px" height="100px" src="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you can not use `position: absolute;` and `white-space: nowrap;`

The Issue can be solved by adding another wrapper inbetween (`.additional-wrapper`).
This wrapper will have the property `white-space: nowrap;`

Also notice that i made a class for your images.

```css
.additional-images-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.additional-wrapper {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.images {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="additional-images-container">
  <div class="additional-wrapper">
    <img class="images" src="">
    <img class="images" src="">
    <img class="images" src="">
    <img class="images" src="">
    <img class="images" src="">
    <img class="images" src="">
    <img class="images" src="">
    <img class="images" src="">
    <img class="images" src="">
    <img class="images" src="">
    <img class="images" src="">
    <img class="images" src="">
    <img class="images" src="">
  </div>
</div>
```